# Mysql multiple table sync

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables from Xenforo:

```
xf_user
xf_user_authenticate
```

Table `xf_user` stores all the info of a user except password hashes, which are stored in `xf_user_authenticate`.

Both tables have the same column called `user_id`.

When data is inserted into `xf_user_authenticate` I need to get the `user_id` from the new inserted row, then use that `user_id` to get the username from `xf_user` and set its value to `xf_user_authenticate`.

I tried this code, but it doesn't work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER name_sync AFTER INSERT ON xf_user_authenticate
begin
SELECT 'username' INTO @username FROM xenforo.xf_user WHERE 'user_id'=NEW.user_id;
UPDATE xenforo.xf_user_authenticate SET 'username' = @username;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have few syntax related issues, in addition you are trying to update the same table where you have after insert trigger. You may need to change the trigger to before insert as

```
delimiter //
create trigger name_sync before insert on xf_user_authenticate
for each row
begin
 declare user_name_sel varchar(100);
 select user_name into user_name_sel 
 from xf_user 
 where user_id = NEW.user_id;
 set new.username = user_name_sel;
end;//

delimiter ;
```

Comment: same... error again: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Comment: Are you running this on msql cli or phpmyadmin.

Comment: phpmyadmin, should I run it in mysql client?

Comment: In PHPMyadmin I suppose you do not need the delimiter since it will have one delimiter check that. But yes you can try the above on mysql client and it should work.

Comment: Not sure if you run the above trigger in mysql command line it should work.

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TRIGGER name_sync BEFORE INSERT ON xf_user_authenticate
BEGIN
    DECLARE cUsername VARCHAR(255);

    SELECT username INTO cUsername FROM xenforo.xf_user WHERE user_id=NEW.user_id;
    SET NEW.username = cUsername;
END
```

Comment: it returns a error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN
    DECLARE cUsername VARCHAR(255)' at line 2